# LIMIT with JOIN using Zend Framework

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, select, join

I have 2 tables `parent`, `children` with relation 1:M. I need a pagination. I use SELECT with JOIN. For 1 parent i have some children. If I try to make `LIMIT 10` this query get total 10 rows. But i need to get only 10 rows from table `parent` with all relations. How can I do it?
Sorry for my english. Thank you in advance.
Mysql query:

```
SELECT `o`.`id` AS `order_id`, `od`.`id` AS `order_destination_id` FROM `order` AS `o`
 LEFT JOIN `order_destination` AS `od` ON o.id = od.order_id LIMIT 5
```

Zend framework:

```
$select = $this->select()
    ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
    ->from(array('o' => 'order'), array('order_id' => 'id'))
    ->joinLeft(array('od' => 'order_destination'), 'o.id = od.order_id', array('order_destination_id' => 'id'))
    ->limit(5);
```

Comment: Can you provide some example of your query, or what you have now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the Zend Framework. Here a plain SQL solution:

```
SELECT `o`.`id` AS `order_id`, `od`.`id` AS `order_destination_id` FROM `order` AS `o`
LEFT JOIN `order_destination` AS `od` ON o.id = od.order_id 
where (select count(*) from order o2 where o2.id > o.id) < 10
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use Zend_Paginator to paginate through one table and then request children for every item:

```
$paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($this->select(), 'DbTableSelect');
$paginator->setItemsCountPerPage(5);
foreach ($paginator as $row) {
    $children = $row->getDependentRowset('ChildrenRule');
}
```